# How to build and archive iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, archive

How to build and archive or archive only iOS application?
I want to archive to .ipa file but cannot select "Product>Archive" or "Product>Build for>Build for Archive" menu (is disabled). I am using Xcode 4.1 on OS Lion. Have any special configuration to building with archive option I don't known?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Please select device from target then simulator as -

[image]